# window.open not working when window.location does

Tags: javascript

```
     $<input class="cartbutton" type="button" onclick="window.open='/cart.php?a=add&pid=1'" value="Order Now »">
```

Unfortunately window.open is not working, however the exact same code with window.location works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` is a method so you'll need to invoke it by calling

```
window.open('/cart.php?a=add&pid=1');
```

window.open also takes several parameters you may want to [check out](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Answer (score 4):

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) is a method call.

```
window.open('example.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

window.open is a function. Do window.open(youLocation);